# How to check whether an element of array exists in string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array which contains words. Also i have a string. I need to check whether an element of array exists in a string.
I've tried but without success. It's not working.

```
function inputValidate() {
    var val = document.getElementById("title");
    var keyWords = ["kerak", "nega", "qanday", "qanaqa", "nimaga", "mi"];
    val.value.trim();
    len = val.value.length - 1;
    lastS = val.value.slice(len);

    if (lastS != "?") {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Savol so`roq belgisi bilan tugashi lozim.";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = " ";
        document.getElementById("error").style.color = "red";
    }

    for (i = 0; i < keyWords.length; i++) {
        if (val.indexOf(keyWords[i]) != -1) {
            document.getElementById("error2").innerHTML = "Gapingizga so`roq gapga o`xshamadi ";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("error2").innerHTML = " ";
        }
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOMWyQ

Comment: I've already used it. Check the code

Comment: what is the value in title? Also you will end up matching words inside of words.

Comment: My bad, still `i = 6` instead of `i<keyWords.length` is an error

Comment: a sentence. It's a string.

Comment: Plus your `error2` `innerHTML` will contain only result of the last iteration.

Comment: why `val.value` instead of just `val` ??

Comment: @DalHundal Many edits ago `val` was a DOM node

Comment: just trying different ways. no result with and without .value

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/drb82zaz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to check whether an element of array exists in a string.

```
// The elements you want to be checked in a certain string.
var KEYWORDS = [ 'world' ];

/**
 * Checks if an element of a keyword array occurs in a certain text string.
 *
 * @param {Array}  keywords   - contains keyword strings
 * @param {String} textString - text string to be checked
 *
 * @return {Boolean} denotes if a match was found.
 */
var keywordExistsInString = function (keywords, textString) {
    // Split the text string for easy matching.
    var words = textString.slice(/\s*\b\s*/);

    // Only interested if ONE of the keywords matches.
    // NOTE: if all keywords must match use 'every()' instead of 'some()'.
    return keywords.some(function (keyword) {

        // Use 'bitwise not' to determine a match.
        // Double negate to convert to a Boolean.
        return !!~words.indexOf(keyword);
    });
};

keywordExistsInString(KEYWORDS, 'hello world'); // true
keywordExistsInString(KEYWORDS, 'hello');       // false
```

Comment: what does `(/\s*\b\s*/)` mean? Could you explain please

Comment: @Sardor `\b` splits on word boundaries and `\s*` matches zero or more white space characters, including space, tab, form feed, line feed. For more info check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Why the "cryptic" `return !!~words.indexOf(keyword)` instead of simply `return words.indexOf(keyword) > -1`

Comment: @Andreas in my opinion the `~` operator is more elegant than `> 1`. The double negation is shorter that using `Boolean()`. But on the other hand, when using `> 1`, the conversion to a Boolean does become superfluous. I guess you might be right that it could be a little bit cryptic though, especially when not dropping comments. I guess it's a matter of taste :)